# SUMIF with INDIRECT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a worksheet name in `C11` which I am using with an `INDIRECT` function to get a cells value. Which is working great, but sometimes the cells aren't always in the same position, so this is giving me a hard time when it comes to doing calculations as I need to modify it each month to take into account any formatting changes.

My current code looks like this.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!R"&ROW(E12)&"C"&COLUMN(E12),FALSE)
```

So I had the idea of using `SUMIF` to getting the cells contents, based on which row it is in.

I have a list of products in `A12:A16` and wish to get the value of the corresponding value from `C12:C16`.

How can I modify my formula to take advantage of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your `SUMIF` criteria would be. This version will look up the value "x" in the worksheet named in C11 in A12:A16 and return the corresponding value from C12:C16

`=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!A12:A16"),"x",INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!C12:C16"))`

Is that what you need?

Alternatively you could use `VLOOKUP`

`=VLOOKUP("x",INDIRECT("'"&$C$11&"'!A12:C16"),3,0)`

Comment: The first answer is perfect :) Thanks!